# Gradle project not getting imported in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-14

I have installed IntelliJ and trying to import a gradle project but facing this error... Please Help me out

[Java is 1.8 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTnXN.png)

[Gradle is not getting configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdG4t.png)

Comment: These links have the images

Comment: Is `JAVA_HOME` set to a Java 6 jdk?

Comment: No that was not a problem .. At the time of configuring we have to select  "Use default gradle wrapper option" and project got opened